# How to map<String,Integer> two csv column with respect to their values in Java?

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I am a new bee in Java and want to map CSV columns according to their values.
My orignal csv data is like:

```
 name,salary,address
 AAA,1000,kkk
 BBB,880,lll
 AAA,90,kkk
 CCC,700,mmm
 BBB,700,lll
```

Expected output should be in Hashmap Key Value pair of two columns name and salary like:

```
Key: AAA Value 1090
Key: BBB Value 1580
Key: CCC Value 700
```

This is my code:

```
        String line = "";
 InputStreamReader inStream = new 
       InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
        buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);  
         try {
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = parseCsvLine(line);

                // I dont know what to do here



            }


            b.close();
            Log.d("Get data from API", "Processing Stop");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 public  String[] parseCsvLine(String line) {
    // Create a pattern to match breaks
    Pattern p =
            Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
    // Split input with the pattern
    String[] fields = p.split(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        // Get rid of residual double quotes
        fields[i] = fields[i].replace("\"", "");
    }
    return fields;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to create your `Map` and put the `map.put(fields[0], fields[1]);`.

Comment: I want to map each name in csv with sum of its salaries.

Comment: You should use csv parser. Try https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to split your line data into part. Then accumulate it to a Map

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] parts = line.split(","); // Split your line, take `,` as delimeter
   String key = parts[0]; // This is your 'AAA'
   Integer value = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // This is your 1000
   if (result.get(key) == null) {
       result.put(key, value); 
   } else {
       result.put(key, result.get(key) + value); // There's already a value here, add it with new value
   }


}
```

The ugly part:

```
   if (result.get(key) == null) {
       result.put(key, value); 
   } else {
       result.put(key, result.get(key) + value); // There's already a value here, add it with new value
   }
```

Can replaced with new Java 8 Map utility:

```
 result.putIfAbsent(key, value); // Put (key, value) if key is absent from the map
 result.compute(key, value, (k, v) -> v + value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying and let you know its working.

Comment: [@user2778724] You're welcome~.

Comment: The `String[] parts = line.split(",");` won't work for all cases, because the values can also contain commas. Such values are usually quoted, so it's better to use a csv parser here. Try commons-csv or opencsv.

Comment: It's match with OP's format. Seriously, if the delimiter is not known beforehand, how did you split it??????? As openCSv use some common delimiter like tab, space, ... only. Add an entire library to just to read a simple file? lol. You made my day.

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn  I have tried your code but displaying result give me following output {AAA=1000 90, BBB=880 700, CCC=700}

Comment: Did you try my code? Post your current code somewhere dude.

Comment: Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

            try {
                while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] parts = parseCsvLine(line); // Split your line, take `,` as delimeter
                    String key = parts[21]; // This is your 'AAA'
                    String value = parts[16]; // This is your 1000
                    if (result.get(key) == null) {
                        result.put(key, value);
                    }

Comment: else {
                        result.put(key, result.get(key) + value); // There's already a value here, add it with new value
                    }


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(result);

Comment: Sorry about the formatting :(

Comment: Can you post your code here https://pastebin.com/ It's easier for me to read

Comment: my csv has some special characters if I split it by , it is not splitting well thats why I am using parseCsvLine function

Comment: Give me a line sample of your csv. Did you parseCsv works well? Did you read the correct part of csv line?

Comment: "user_id","cookie_user","Item","title","description","resource_url","link","tags","Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minutes","Seconds","Day of Week","date","topic_coverage","view_coverage","complexity","community_id","type","scope","scope_topic_coverage"
"cd330929-4725-441b-8091-5e4581722bd5","d2405086-fc67-bd45-345e-fb7fa7131dd5","30075056-e7a2-4636-8c68-3f277a3d3951","Calculating Probabilities of Combined Event? At grade","This lesson covers how to calculate the probability of combined

Comment: events.<br/><p>It is an educational content of <a href='http://www.ck12.org/' target='_blank'>CK-12 Foundation</a> (to access some of the CK-12 contents you must be logged in).</p>","https://didactalia.net/comunidad/materialeducativo/recurso/calculating-probabilities-of-combined-event-at/30075056-e7a2-4636-8c68-3f277a3d3951","http://www.ck12.org/probability/Probability-of-Compound-Events/lesson/Calculating-Probabilities-of-Combined-Events/",

Comment: "calculating probabilities of combined events;complement;event;independent events;probability;trigonometry;binomial expansion;combinations;dependent;factorial;fundamental counting principle;independent;intersection;ma;",2017,11,10,8,34,1,"Monday","2017-12-10T08:34:01Z",0.060842433697347896,0.03796203796203795,0,"f22e757b-8116-4496-bec4-ae93a4792c28","resourceVisited","probability",0.16770186335403728
"cd330929-4725-441b-8091-5e4581722bd5","d2405086-fc67-bd45-

Comment: 345e-fb7fa7131dd5","2afe09d9-c069-4c86-964a-61c9c6a4209c","Recurso online para aprender que es la ciencia y sus ramas derivadas","<p>material educativo sobre ciencia y ramas derivadas</p>\n","https://didactalia.net/comunidad/materialeducativo/recurso/recurso-online-para-aprender-que-es-la-ciencia-y/2afe09d9-c069-4c86-964a-61c9c6a4209c","http://cienciaweb.com/material-teorico/ciencia/",

Comment: "fisica;quimica;naturaleza;ciencias de la naturaleza;ciencias naturales;ciencias físicas;ciencia;método científico;ciencias formales;hipótesis (método científico);teoría científica;",2017,11,10,8,33,37,"Monday","2017-12-10T08:33:37Z",0.060842433697347896,0.007042253521126762,22.044,"f22e757b-8116-4496-bec4-ae93a4792c28","resourceVisited","probability",0.060842433697347896

Comment: Dude, post your csv header and some lines at pastebin.com. I can't read

Comment: You can access them on https://pastebin.com/KztHjmv3

Comment: which field name you want to combine? Your parser function is wrong

Comment: I want to combine "complexity" and "scope"